# With Docker, what files persist between stages?

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

There are few ways in which I can phrase my question. I find documentation lacking around how to use an artifact from a previous stage - specifically the example [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages).

My use case is I'm using a docker stage to `makepkg` an arch linux package, which requires many build-time dependencies (including a 500MB `go` language toolkit, creation of a non-root user etc), and I don't want to keep those in the image.

Inside first stage, do I need to `COPY` the resulting pkg.tar.xz for using it with `COPY --from=` inside the second stage? What's the lifetime of this artifact?